# How do I set dynamically different font size for each item in series of Treemap chart of amchart4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts, treemap, amcharts4

I am using amchart4 charting library to create a Treemap chart. I've created bullets to show some additional text on each item of series. How do I set different font size for each item's label in series according to the size of the item.

[Treemap chart with labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHXOp.png)

```
/* Add bullet labels */
var level1_bullet = level1.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
level1_bullet.locationY = 0.5;
level1_bullet.locationX = 0.5;
level1_bullet.label.text = "{name}";
level1_bullet.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
/* Here I need to set different font size for each bullet */
level1_bullet.label.fontSize = "{differentFontSize}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
level1_bullet.label.text = "[font-size:{differentFontSize}]{name}";
```